# Data not being stored on SQLite DB in Java src folder

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I have made a simple game that uses SQLite to store the scores. When connected to the database in the default SQLite folder, the database connection works. I then added the database to my src folder and connected to it using the following code I found on Stackoverflow:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
           String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:src/Scores";

            Connection conn = (Connection)

            DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);

            Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

But the problem is now the scores are not being stored, and also no error messages are coming up. How can I get the application to connect and store on the database in the src folder?

**UPDATE**

I placed the database into the src folder by using copy and paste. When I open the database directly from the src folder, SQLite basically recreates the database with no tables. I tried re-entering the table into the blank DB and when I do a clean build of the application, the DB has no tables again.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: you dont commit your changes

Comment: What do you mean I don't commit my changes? Please elaborate

Comment: jdbc connections have a flag "autoCommit", when it is set to false, you need to commit explicitely conn.commit(), if it is set to true(default i think) closing the statement/connection triggers the commit automatically. stmt.close()/conn.close()

Comment: Okay, I'm still learning how to use databases, so what would be the best way to correct this problem?

Comment: first i would say, close your statement and connection and see if its persisted

Comment: Okay, I just tried closing the statement and connection and the problem still persists

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Could it be the way I added the database to the src folder? All I did was copy paste it into the src folder. Is there some other way it should have been added?

Comment: Think you should try to remove the db and see if its created via your code. Sqlite should create the file by itself, perhaps better to start there.

Comment: I removed the db and now an error comes up saying:  "java.sql.SQLException: no such table: user_scores"

Comment: Okay I found out what the problem is. Whenever I copy the database into the src folder and/or do a clean and build of the application, Java seems to remove the tables from the database. That's why it is not working because the db is blank. How can I fix this?